# How can I make my generic parameter conform to OR in Swift and how can I found the conformation of parameter?

Tags: swift

I want build a function which accept to kind of protocols, the function should work if one of protocols passed, I have 2 issue with this function, first I do not know how I can apply **OR** to protocols, and second i do not know how can I find out my incoming value inside the function conform to which protocol, then I could run right code!

```
func printFunction<T: CustomStringConvertible OR CustomDebugStringConvertible>(value: T) {    // 1: issue with OR!

    if value.description {              // 2: issue with finding out which protocol conformation is!
        print(value.description)
    }
    else if value.debugDescription {    // 3: issue with finding out which protocol conformation is!
        print(value.debugDescription)
    }
    else {
        print("not printable!")
    }
 
}
```

Comment: There is no OR operator for protocol conformance

Comment: Then I guess I should split the function for 2 protocol with same name, right?

Comment: yes. What you need is to implement two methods. One for each. Btw no need to explicitly type description when using CustomStringConvertible `func printFunction<T: CustomStringConvertible>(value: T) { print(value) }` and `func printFunction<T: CustomDebugStringConvertible>(value: T) { print(value.debugDescription) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OR operator for protocol conformance. Protocol is like a contract you can't conform to one or another. You need to conform to both. What you need is to implement two methods. One for each. Btw no need to explicitly type description when using CustomStringConvertible:

---

```
func printFunction<T: CustomStringConvertible>(value: T) { print(value) }
```

---

```
func printFunction<T: CustomDebugStringConvertible>(value: T) { print(value.debugDescription) }
```